# Do anti-collision lights in aircraft lose intensity over time?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, aircraft-external-lights

Do anti-collision lights installed in aircraft lose their intensity over time and need to be replaced every few hundred hours of operation?

Comment: Wouldn't the manufacturers love that.

Answer (score 5):

No, however the intensity is a feature of the bulb rather than the purpose.

Historically, incandescent bulbs were used, followed by Xenon flashtubes. Currently, LEDs are used in [anti-collision lights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-collision_light) and [other lights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigation_light) on aircraft.

Please note that there are some requirements needed for bulbs used. They are mentioned in [14 CFR 25.1399](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/25.1399):

> Show a white light for at least 2 nautical miles at night under clear
>   atmospheric conditions.

Comment: The Xenon flashtubes don't seem to lose intensity, but they do start to intermittently fail to fire as they age.  LEDs OTOH are well known (as a general technology) to lose intensity over time.